# Reveng to find out CRC algorithm in closed protocol

Tags: algorithm, math, reverse, checksum, crc

I have one machine with closed protocol and another device "gateway Modbus" from the same manufacter. This gateway convert this protocol to RS-485 Modbus.

When I send a command packet (modbus function 16) to gateway, gateway send (converted) specific packet to the machine and when I inject this packet over simple UART communication, machine can understand and change values too. I create a list with some cloned commands, but I need to know how CRC/checksum/etc is calculed (I think) to create custom packets.

I already used RevEng tool (https://reveng.sourceforge.io/) and CRCcalculator (https://crccalc.com/) trying to find some common crc algorithm with cloned packets, but none worked.

Some cloned packets, where 2 last bytes is CRC/etc. In this packets I changed the temperature value from 0x11 to 0x15 and last 2 bytes changed too (maybe crc/checksum/etc):

```
9A56F1FE0EB9001100000100641C
9A56F1FE0EB90012000001006720
9A56F1FE0EB90013000001006620
9A56F1FE0EB9001400000100611C
9A56F1FE0EB9001500000100601C
```

RevEng output:

```
./reveng -w 16 -l -s 9A56F1FE0EB9001100000100641C 9A56F1FE0EB90012000001006720 9A56F1FE0EB90013000001006620 9A56F1FE0EB9001400000100611C 9A56F1FE0EB9001500000100601C
./reveng: no models found
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a CRC. The second-to-last byte is the exclusive-or sum of the preceding bytes. I'm not sure what the last byte is, but since it is only taking on two different values in your example, it does not appear to be part of a check value. Or if it is, it's a rather ineffective check value algorithm.